# React: useState array doesn't change when state change method called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Array state doesn't change when state change method is beign called :

```
const [arrayOfDocuments, setArrayOfDocuments] = useState([]);
```

i tried : `setArrayOfDocuments(...[]); or setArrayOfDocuments([]);`

where i use my method :

```
  const pushToArrayOfDocuments = (obj) => {
    const arr = arrayOfDocuments;
    if (obj.filename && obj.file && obj.expiredate && obj.doctype) {
      const index = arr.map((e) => e.filename).indexOf(obj.filename);
      if (index !== -1) {
        arr[index] = obj;
      } else {
        arr.push(obj);
      }
      setArrayOfDocuments(arr);
    }
  };
```

Maybe the problem is push? and i should do `setArrayOfDocuments(...arr); or  setArrayOfDocuments(prev => [...prev,...arr])` but if doing so i guess it will go in  infinte rendering as i'm passing `pushToArrayOfDocuments` to the subcomponents.
Like this :

```
OperatorDocument
                  key={`Durc${count}`}
                  title="Durc"
                  description="Descrizione Durc"
                  setDocument={pushToArrayOfDocuments}
                  document={getObjectByName('Durc')}
                  filedocname="Durc"
                />
```

edit :
doing like this : `setArrayOfDocuments([...arr]);`
i get `Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.`
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `arr` will still equal `arr`, so no state change will be triggered.   You could just do -> `setArrayOfDocuments([...arr]);`

Comment: @Keith that way it will go in infinte rendering any solution ?

Comment: `so i guess it will go in infinte rendering as i'm passing pushToArrayOfDocuments` This is **the** problem. Why does that changed reference cause infinite rendering? This is where the real issue lies - show the `useEffect` in `OperatorDocument` Never use `push` (or `splice`) or anything that mutates a thing in React.

Comment: Put the old array into a new variable, i.e. `updatedArray`, add the changes to that, set the state to that array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you should never mutate `useState`'s state directly, use them as immutable entities. If you want to use it as initial value, clone it before:

```
const arr = [...arrayOfDocuments]
// or
const arr = arrayOfDocuments.slice()
```

Secondly, you are passing the same state array to the setter, then the state will not be updated. Cloning the state will solve this second point.

Finally, the best way to construct a new state from the old value is using a function:

```
setState(oldValue => (/* construct new state based on old value */))
```

this will avoid using a value that is not up to date.
At the end, you will have:

```
const pushToArrayOfDocuments = (obj) => {
  if (obj.filename && obj.file && obj.expiredate && obj.doctype) {
    setArrayOfDocuments(oldArr => {
        const arr = oldArr.slice();
        const index = arr.map((e) => e.filename).indexOf(obj.filename);

        if (index !== -1) {
          arr[index] = obj;
        } else {
          arr.push(obj);
        }

        return arr;
      }
    )
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to clone your array before adding it to state.

```js
const arr = arrayOfDocuments.slice();
```

Full snippet:

```js
const pushToArrayOfDocuments = (obj) => {
  if (obj.filename && obj.file && obj.expiredate && obj.doctype) {
    const arr = arrayOfDocuments.slice();
    const index = arr.findIndex(({ filename }) => filename === obj.filename);

    if (index > -1) {
      arr[index] = obj;
    } else {
      arr.push(obj);
    }

    setArrayOfDocuments(arr);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I add a similar problem, and I solved by

instead of

> const arr = arrayOfDocuments

try spreading the initial array

> const arr = [...arrayOfDocuments]